# For Windows MSVC, where is the QWORD data type defined?

Tags: c, windows

Getting an `identifier "QWORD" is undefined` error in this code

[image: qword]

According to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/ac050bbf-a821-4fab-bccf-d95d892f428f), a QWORD is defined as

```
typedef unsigned __int64 QWORD;
```

As a workaround, I've manually added the definition

```
typedef uint64_t QWORD;
```

It seems odd these common data types BYTE, WORD and DWORD are defined, but the QWORD is not?

Comment: The `WORD` and `DWORD` types have names that Microsoft came up with in the 1980s (or perhaps earlier). Perhaps they realized it was a silly naming convention in later years.

Comment: There is a 64-bit `DWORDLONG` type but that name is even sillier than `DWORD`. See [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types). It mentions `QWORD` but doesn't say where it is defined!

Comment: I'll go with a DWORDLONG for now. Kinda makes sense since a DWORD is an `unsigned long` and a LONG is a `long`, so a DWORDLONG is an `unsigned long long`. Thanks!

Comment: looking at `winnt.h` it seems MS uses `ULONGLONG` for this purpose in a general sense. There is also `DWORD64` because of course

Comment: @IanAbbott look at the table at the bottom of that page and you'll see that they're available in *BaseTsd.h;
WinDef.h;
WinNT.h*

Comment: @phuclv For all of the types except `QWORD` it says "This type is declared in *[name of header file]* as follows:", but for `QWORD` it just says "This type is declared as follows:" but it doesn't say where!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found `QWORD` in `winDNS.h` as shown by this code, which compiles in the older 2015 32-bit MSVC and in the 2022 64-bit MSVC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winDNS.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(QWORD));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
8
```

The definition occurs in these (MSVC 2015) header files

```
Sspi.h
WinDNS.h
datacontainer.h
wmcodecdsp.h
wmnetsourcecreator.h
wmscontext.h
wmsdkidl.h
wmsincomingcounters.h
wmspacket.h
```

Comment: Interesting to include a windows header related to `Domain Name System (DNS)`, but it's a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I've added a list of header files. Not all of them can be found by including them, for example `#include <datacontainer.h>` is not found by the compiler. I think it might be a relic from the 2009 compiler.

Comment: You can repeat the same `typedef` as many times as you like as long as it's identical to any previous. So you don't really need to find a header file.